# Why am I getting a syntax error for this SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

The Syntax error is at WHERE [MaywoodsDateTime] Does it need + or a comma? I'm not sure what to do since the error inst very specific.

I've tried using a ; but then I get the same error

```
  SELECT TOP (50)   [EventDateTime]
         ,[EventType]
         ,[NHSNumber]
         ,[StateID]
         ,[UserID]
         ,[DocumentUUID]
         ,[DocumentTitle]
         ,[ClientIP]       
          FROM [ATNA-Update-Test].[dbo].[log_LPRES_ATNA_Simplified]
         "WHERE [EventType] = 'MIG' "                    
         "WHERE [MaywoodsDateTime] IS NULL" 
         "AND   [MaywoodsAuditID]    IS NULL" 
         "ORDER BY[EventDateTime] ";
```

Comment: Only one `where` clause is allowed.   And double quotes are not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the double quotes and use only one `where` statement.

```
SELECT TOP (50)   [EventDateTime]
         ,[EventType]
         ,[NHSNumber]
         ,[StateID]
         ,[UserID]
         ,[DocumentUUID]
         ,[DocumentTitle]
         ,[ClientIP]       
          FROM [ATNA-Update-Test].[dbo].[log_LPRES_ATNA_Simplified]
         WHERE [EventType] = 'MIG' AND [MaywoodsDateTime] IS NULL
         AND   [MaywoodsAuditID] IS NULL
         ORDER BY[EventDateTime];
```

Comment: @Elliot.NHS No need. It's my pleasure to help you solve your problem. Enjoy :)